# How to setup email server on Mac os x?

Tags: macos, email, operating-system

I need to sent many e-mail for advertising.
I can use the command 'mail' to send plain text e-mail,but can't send html e-mail.
Is there such a software(for mac) which can send html e-mail through the mail server built on Mac os x?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using apache James, its a fully functional email server, very easy to setup (as simple as unzip & run). ofcourse you need to have java installed first.

here is a [link](http://james.apache.org/) to the apache james site.

you can download the current stable version of the james server from [here](http://james.apache.org/download.cgi#Apache_James_2.3.2_is_the_stable_version;)